# Add/remove CSS class based on #hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

i have two forms on my website. one `.login-form` and one `.registration-form`. by default the login form has a `display: block` property and the registration form has a `display: none` property. i have a button to switch between the two forms. that already works beautifully.

now i want to switch those properties based on the url hash. so if you visit `/user.html#registration` i want to see the registration form rather than the login form first.

how can i achieve that?
i really appreciate your help!

jaro.

Comment: [__`onhashchange`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short script to read the hash should do:

```
<script>
// Add this block to where your "after page load" code starts. 
// If you use a framework, you should adjust the solution to your framework.
if (location.hash && location.hash === "#registration") {
    // or whichever way your app switches between the two
    document.body.classList.add("show-registration");
} // else it'll show login, as intended.
</script>
```

If your CSS isn't set up for it already:

```
<style>
body.show-registration .login-form {
    display: none;
}
body.show-registration .registration-form {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty much what you are looking for :

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => {
  if (window.location.hash === "registration") {
     document.querySelector(".registration-form").style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

Comment: but this is not adding the class,it directly changes the style attribute. if you define your classes, you can do document.querySelector(".registration-form").classList.add("your class") or .classList.remove("your class");

Comment: you are welcome, if it solves your problem, can you approve the answer please